# AWSDatabaseMigrationService Error: no authentication credentials

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to set up AWS DMS to copy data from S3 to Redshift.

For configuration of the source endpoint (S3), after setting the parameters, when I run the test, get the following error:

> AWSDatabaseMigrationService: Cannot change the engine for endpoint
>   with no authentication credentials

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the instructions to the letter 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html

specifically:

> **Prerequisites When Using S3 as a Source for AWS DMS**
>
> When you use S3 as a source for AWS DMS, the source S3 bucket that you
>   use must be in the same AWS Region as the AWS DMS replication instance
>   that you use to migrate your data. In addition, the AWS account you
>   use for the migration must have read access to the source bucket.
>
> The AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role assigned to the user
>   account used to create the migration task must have the following set
>   of permissions.

Comment: Thank you, the only change I made was moving the data in the same region my DMS instance is and issue is solved now.